# Reshaping 3D numpy array for MATLAB requirement compatibility

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

Given an array of shape `3,2,2`

```
np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]])
```

I would like to reshape it into shape `2,2,3`.

Downstream, this reshape data will be processed in MATLAB, and for some reason, the MATLAB-Package require the array to be shaped `2,2,3`.

In MATLAB, the expected output should be

```
val(:,:,1) =

     1     2
     3     4


val(:,:,2) =

     5     6
     7     8


val(:,:,3) =

     9    10
    11    12
```

Simply reshaping `arr.reshape(2,2,3)` does not produced what I intend it to be.

Update:
[@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70236364/6446053) proposal produced

```
val(:,:,1) =

   1   3
   2   4


val(:,:,2) =

   5   7
   6   8


val(:,:,3) =

    9   11
   10   12
```

Comment: What does `arr.reshape(2,2,3)` produce and why is it wrong?

Comment: play with the `order` as well.  Reshape isn't enough to match numpy and matlab

Comment: How will you transfer the array?  `scipy.io.savemat` may do the desired conversion.

Comment: Thanks for dropping by @hpaulj, Im planning use the np.save feature

Comment: How would you read it with Matlab?

Comment: Thanks for the interest @hpaulj, I will be using the package which is accessible via the following link: https://github.com/kwikteam/npy-matlab . I have tried it and it work like a charm

Comment: @rpb have you had a chance to try out my solution and check what you get in matlab? let me know if you feel anything is missing from my answer e.g. if you'd like examples of moveaxis vs swapaxes for completeness etc.

Comment: Thanks for the interest in this OP @rudolfovic. I yet to check this with MATLAB. Will update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```py
np.moveaxis(x, 0, 2)
```

Your original shape is (3, 2, 2). This line moves axis[0] and rolls it over to axis[2] (shifting the other 2 axes left). And so you get:

```py
>>> x[:, :, 0]
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: I don't have matlab to actually test this out but if this doesn't work then you might need to switch the two "2" dimensions. You can achieve this with `np.swapaxes(x, 0, 2)` (this will simply switch axis[0] for axis[2] without shifting anything)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [29]: arr = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]])
In [30]: arr
Out[30]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]])
In [31]: arr.shap
Out[31]: (3, 2, 2)
```

MATLAB stores matrices like numpy's order 'F', with trailing dimension outermost.  That's easiest to visualize with 2d as a transpose. Let's try that on the 3d:

```
In [32]: arr1 = arr.T
In [33]: arr1.shape
Out[33]: (2, 2, 3)
In [34]: arr1
Out[34]: 
array([[[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 3,  7, 11]],

       [[ 2,  6, 10],
        [ 4,  8, 12]]])
```

MATLAB displays 3d arrays by iterating on the last dimension, its "plane":

```
In [36]: for i in range(3):print(arr1[:,:,i])
[[1 3]
 [2 4]]
[[5 7]
 [6 8]]
[[ 9 11]
 [10 12]]
```

I don't have your MATLAB npy loader, but can explore how `io.savemat/loadmat` does the transfer.  This is works with the MATLAB formated files:

```
In [37]: from scipy import io
In [38]: io.savemat('test3d.mat',{'arr':arr, 'arr1':arr1})
In [39]: io.loadmat('test3d.mat')
Out[39]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Sun Dec  5 08:29:25 2021',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'arr': array([[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],
 
        [[ 5,  6],
         [ 7,  8]],
 
        [[ 9, 10],
         [11, 12]]]),
 'arr1': array([[[ 1,  5,  9],
         [ 3,  7, 11]],
 
        [[ 2,  6, 10],
         [ 4,  8, 12]]])}
```

In an Octave session:

```
>> load test3d.mat
>> arr
arr =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   3
   5   7
   9  11

ans(:,:,2) =

   2   4
   6   8
  10  12

>> arr1
arr1 =

ans(:,:,1) =

   1   3
   2   4

ans(:,:,2) =

   5   7
   6   8

ans(:,:,3) =

   9  11
  10  12
```

and the ravelled display shows that the transpose preserved the original `numpy` data value order:

```
>> arr1(:)'
ans =

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12

>> arr(:)'
ans =

   1   5   9   3   7  11   2   6  10   4   8  12
```

An alternative transpose moves the 3 to the end, but maintains order in the first 2

```
In [40]: arr2 = arr.transpose(1,2,0)
In [41]: arr2
Out[41]: 
array([[[ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 2,  6, 10]],

       [[ 3,  7, 11],
        [ 4,  8, 12]]])
In [42]: for i in range(3):print(arr2[:,:,i])
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
[[5 6]
 [7 8]]
[[ 9 10]
 [11 12]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the `savemat` , this remove the need for 3rd party extension in the MATLAB.

Comment: Per your suggestion,in the octave session, the 1,2,3,4 was position in term of coordinate (0,0) ,(0,1),(1,0),(1,1), respectively. But, what if one desire to position the 1,2,3,4 in (0,0) ,(1,0),(0,1),(1,1), respectively. I have update the OP to reflect this requirement. Thanks @hpaulj